# Insert UImageVIew into UITextField

Tags: cocoa, xcode3.2

How can I add an image to a textfield? I saw it in a few apps, but can't get around it. Also based on the location of the curser, the imageView will be initialized (add image to next line). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean insert an image into the text box of the textfield I don't believe this is possible.  What are you trying to accomplish?  There are probably more appropriate ways of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes We can insert imageview into textfield  with the following code.

```
 UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text_line.png"]];
 myView.center = CGPointMake(5, 27);                     
 [letterField insertSubview:myView atIndex:0];// mgViewTitleBackGround is image
 [myView release];
```

Go through this code.

Comment: Doesn't position the view according to the location of the cursor, so I don't think this actually answers the question.